# I’m having issues with chirp not uploading the program to my baofeng GT-3WP

Tags: baofeng, software, chirp

I have a baofeng gt-3WP and am trying to program it in CHIRP but the tab that says upload to radio is greyed out and will not respond

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your cable see if you plugged it all the way in to the side of the radio.
2. Check to see  if the radio is on a frequency that's not in use
3. the radio should be on.
4. Turn the volume up.
5. Go in the radio menu and click download from radio, follow the prompts.
6. Their you should be able to upload to radio after you have configured the channel listing.
   F8hp user here.